# onkeypress does not call function

Tags: javascript, html, onkeypress

I need to call a js function everytime a key is pressed in a textbox:

```
<html>
    <script>
        function checkValidity() {
            alert("Checking...");
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onkeypress="checkValidity()">
    </body>
</html>
```

The alert, however, never get displayed. What's wrong with this code?

**UPDATE**

The script is actually in a separate js file but I'm certain it's declared correctly because if I call `checkValidity()` from the body's `onload` I do get the alert.

Comment: @MircoWidmer that question concerns regular expressions. This is completely different.

Comment: I'd change `onkeypress` to `onkeyup` to avoid missing backspace, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your markup is right but the function name `checkValidity` is now an internal keyword for elements

Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity

You can change the name of the function thats all

```html
<html>
    <script>
        function checkMyValidity() {
            alert("Checking...");
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onkeypress="checkMyValidity()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

checkValidity is Javascript's form validation method. Change the method name. Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script>

        function checkValid() {
    alert("You pressed a key inside the input field");
}

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onkeypress="checkValid()">
    </body>


</html>
```

I think it is working

Comment: checkValidity is Javascript's form validation method